# Encoding error in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am testing Delphi 2010 and I was with the following mistake:
Do I enter with this chain of characters "096 - Construção Ltda" and do I only move her/it for another variable and do look at him/it what leaves "096 - ConstruÃ§Ã£o Ltda", does anybody know how to find out that that???

***Entrance base***

*001 Alcides João Pereira

002 Alvir Maçaneiro

003 Auto Elétrica Imamura Ltda

004 Auto Peças Araújo

005 Auto Peças Porto Eixo Ltda

006 Auto Peças União

007 Azambuja Industria Comercio de Materiais de Construção Ltda

008 Balaroti Comercio De Materiais De Construção Ltda

009 Baldissera Logística e Transportes Ltda Me

010 Battistella Veículos Pesados Ltda

011 Berton Diesel Auto Peças

012 Bisolo Materiais de Construção Ltda*

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   tfEntrada : TextFile;
   intI, intJ : Integer;
   strA, strS : String;

   procedure lerUm; //To read a registration of the file text
   begin
      inc( intI );
      ReadLn( tfEntrada, strS );

      strA := Copy( IntToStr( intI + 1000 ), 2, 3 ) + ' - ';
      Edit1.Text := strS;

   end;

begin

   intI := 0;
   AssignFile( tfEntrada, 'nomes_tst_0001.txt' );
   Reset( tfEntrada );

   lerUm;

   while not Eof ( tfEntrada ) do
   begin

     mmEntrada.Lines.Add( strA + strS ); //I move for TMemo(mmEntrada, mmSaida), in the form

     mmSaida.Lines.Add( strA + strS );

     lerUm;

  end;

  CloseFile( tfEntrada );

end;
```

***result base***

*001 - Alcides JoÃ£o Pereira

002 - Alvir MaÃ§aneiro

003 - Auto ElÃ©trica Imamura Ltda

004 - Auto PeÃ§as AraÃºjo

005 - Auto PeÃ§as Porto Eixo Ltda

006 - Auto PeÃ§as UniÃ£o

007 - Azambuja Industria Comercio de Materiais de ConstruÃ§Ã£o Ltda

008 - Balaroti Comercio De Materiais De ConstruÃ§Ã£o Ltda

009 - Baldissera LogÃ­stica e Transportes Ltda Me

010 - Battistella VeÃ­culos Pesados Ltda

011 - Berton Diesel Auto PeÃ§as
012 - Bisolo Materiais de ConstruÃ§Ã£o Ltda*

Comment: The second string is the UTF-8 encoded form of the first string.  Are you assigning your string value to a UTF8String variable? Please show the actual code you are have trouble with.

Comment: Your string values are stil being UTF-8 encoded.  I suspect it is because of your use of old-syle Pascal file I/O, which does not support Unicode.  I strongly suggest you use newer-style VCL-style file I/O instead, such as by loading the file into a TStringList and then looping though that.  And next time, please use StackOverflow's code formatting capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use AssignFile. It is a legacy code and it does not work with UnicodeStrings. Instead, use a TStringList or a TFileStream to read the file.

[untested]

```
procedure ReadFile;  
var  
  vFileReader : TstringList;  
begin  
  vFileReader := TStringList.Create;  
  try
    vFileReader.LoadFromFile('nomes_tst_0001.txt');  
    mmEntrada.Lines.Assign(vFileReader);  
  finally
    vFileReader.Free;  
  end;
end;
```

**EDITED**

Another nice solution is the follow function i wrote a long time ago:

[tested]

```
function GetFileAsString(aFileName: string; aOffSet : Integer = 0; aChunkSize: Integer = -1): string;
var
  vStream: TFileStream;
  vBuffer: TBytes;
  vCurEncoding, vDefEncoding: TEncoding;
  vOffSet: Integer;
  vFileSize: Int64;
begin
  vCurEncoding := nil;
  vDefEncoding := TEncoding.Default;
  vStream := TFileStream.Create(aFileName, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    if aChunkSize > 0 then begin
      vFileSize := aChunkSize;
    end
    else begin
      vFileSize := vStream.Size;
    end;
    vStream.Position := aOffSet;
    SetLength(vBuffer, vFileSize);
    vStream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(vBuffer)^, vFileSize);
    vOffSet := TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(vBuffer, vCurEncoding);
    if (vCurEncoding <> vDefEncoding) then begin
      vBuffer := TEncoding.Convert(vCurEncoding, vDefEncoding, vBuffer, vOffSet,   vFileSize - vOffSet);
    end;
    Result := vDefEncoding.GetString(vBuffer);
  finally
    vStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This function is capable of handling unicode strings (with BOM) and also ansistring. Actually, it can read all kind of text files you have.

Comment: This will only work if the file encoding is the default encoding (unless there is a BOM). I would use the overload with the additional Encoding: TEncoding parameter (of course I need to know the file encoding, otherwise I would be in serious trouble)

Comment: +1; old-style file handling routines (`AssignFile`, `Reset`, `Read`, `ReadLn`, `Write`, `WriteLn`, `Close`) don't work with Unicode.

Comment: @mjn yeah, you are right. I just wanted to show how to do it simple.

Comment: @Jeroen: Well, they *do* work with Unicode, you just need to encode/decode explicitly.